# How to sort property file values in order?

Tags: java, properties, set

I have a property file named `sample.properties` and having values like below,

```
a=A
b=B
c=C
```

Am getting property values through `ResourceBundle` and stored in a set like below,

```
private Set<Entry<Object, Object>> sampleSet = null;
for(Properties properties:sampleProperties){
            sampleSet = properties.entrySet();      
        }
```

But while I show property files in UI , the out put come like below

```
c=C
a=A
b=B
```

which is not in order.

Comment: I want to display the values same in sample.properties

Answer (score 1):

`Set` will not maintain the order of keys, if you want maintain order, You can use `TreeSet`

```
private TreeSet<Entry<Object, Object>> sampleSet = new TreeSet<Entry<Object, Object>>();
for(Properties properties:sampleProperties){
        sampleSet.addAll(properties.entrySet());      
}
```

Comment: it shows error because hashtable can not cast comparable method.

Answer (score 0):

Use List instead of Set to get the same order as in properties file.

Answer (score 0):

**Which is not in order?**

**Properties file Ordered**
If you want to order elements is order present in properties file use `List`

```
private List<Entry<Object, Object>> sampleSet = null;
```

**Natural Ordering** - If you want natural sorted order and unique elements then use `Set` implementation.

```
private TreeSet<Entry<Object, Object>> sampleSet = null;
```

**Custom Ordering** - If you want your own order then use `Comparator` or `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are expecting to get properties to be inserted in same order as it is there in the properties file.

This is not possible unless you create your own Properties class. Basically java Properties class extends HashTable, which stores  in hash order of the key. Hence through java Properties it is not quite possible. Instead if you want you can go through the implementation, Create your own Property class which extends TreeMap. You have to implement load method such a way that it reads line by line and inserts. By doing this you can achieve your goal.

Now my question is why do you want to do that? Properties is implemented to make the searching faster, not to keep things in order.

To read file from resource bundle you can use this,

```
Class cls = Class.forName("YOUR_CLASS_NAME");

     // returns the ClassLoader object associated with this Class
     ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
     // input stream
     InputStream i = cLoader.getResourceAsStream("propertyfileresource");
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));

     // reads each line
     String l;
     StringBuffer buff=new StringBuffer();
     while((l = r.readLine()) != null) {
        buff.append(l);
     }
```

Comment: I just want to display the values in UI same as in property file.

Comment: but in result the values are rearranged

Comment: To do so why you need to read it as property file? Just read it as a File, get the String and display in UI line by line. You can keep property object for other operation but not for display purpose. You can use this: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(File propFile)

Comment: am using customized ResourceBundle method to read property file.

Comment: You can read resource as stream. I have updated the answer please check. hope it will help.